# java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream - reading from HTTP

Tags: java, http, zlib

I tried looking around for similar problem but couldn't find any solution that resemble my problem:

I use the following piece of code to read from HttpUrlConnection:

```
public static BufferedReader getConnectionReader(HttpURLConnection con, String url)
        throws Exception {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.connect();
    if (cm != null) {
        cm.storeCookies(con);
    }
    if (con.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding") != null
            && con.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding").equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(con.getInputStream())));
    } else
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
}
```

Reading is performed in the following way:

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
reader = Utils.getConnectionReader(con, "http://www.site.com/page.html");
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.info(line);
}
```

Sometimes I get the mentioned exception:

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

When I can, I catch this exception and retry the operation - successfully.

The problem is that I don't know what is causing this exception to pop.
It happens quite randomly.

I want to believe it is a network issue.

Anyone found a way to fully solve such problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method your using is less than ideal for binary formats like GZip, I assume you are doing that just for testing? Apart from that and the bug with the HTTPURLConnection, there's not much else in code that could be causing the issue. I would recommend reading using byte buffer swapping, at least to eliminate that as a possible source of error.

Comment: thank you for the response.
i use this code to read html pages - text pages.
most are not compressed.

what do you mean about the bug with HttpUrlConnection?
thanks again.

Comment: @tzafrir - you are declaring an empty variable *con* and passing it into your function, where you initialize it. If you intend to use that *con* object then note that it will not be initialized when control returns out of your function, since Java is pass-by-value. If however, you do not intend on using it then theres no need to pass it into the function in the first place.

Comment: The workaround was to catch this specific exception and retry the request.
I assume it is caused by network problems.